# Get Twitter Mentions for not authenticated user

Tags: php, twitter

when I look at the API Docs of Twitter for mentions it says the following

`Returns the 20 most recent mentions (tweets containing a users's @screen_name) for the authenticating user. The timeline returned is the equivalent of the one seen when you view your mentions on twitter.com. This method can only return up to 800 tweets. See Working with Timelines for...`

However, another site I found gets the mentions without having the user authenticated. 
[image]

How exactly do I get those mentions? From the picture I posted it looks like the site gets only the public data, so how does it get the mentions when the API states that the mentions are only for the authenticating user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine they're using the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming) to access all tweets and process them, as this would allow them to see how many tweets mention that particular user.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I will have a look at it tomorrow and then respond. :)

Comment: Hey. I just tested it out, but it seems that the Streaming API is in real time. Is this correct? If yes, it wouldn't be the correct approach, since I need to go back "in time" to get the mentions. Any other ideas?

Comment: Correct, it is real time, so they would have been collecting these for a while, but unfortunately Twitter don't offer a way to load mentions back in time. I needed it myself some time ago and they don't offer an API for it. The mentions timeline only goes back 800 mentions as it is, and the only thing you can do to get historical mentions for someone else is to use the search API to search for "@handle", however this only goes back 1 week. Unfortunately it's just not something they give you historical access to.

Comment: Hey, yes. Nonetheless I voted your answer up, because of the help. Thanks. Yes, I also searched for the handle, but it doesn't work always. My handle @tzfrs doesn't return any results whereas I posted a test post recently and have been mentiond about 4-5 times. Also 1 week old data would be enough as a start as I will be collecting them too, but unforationaly, as I said it doesn't find my handle.. :(

Seems like the only option is to start collecting today and get the own mentions. But this would also mean to have a 24h service running that gets every tweet. Sounds like a resourceful service.

Comment: I don't think the search API will always find stuff immediately, the streaming API should though. But yes, if you need this sort of data collected then it does need to be collected constantly in real time.

Comment: Wow. You're right. Just tested the search API again and it returns my tweet. Where did you read that it will only show the tweets of the last 7 days? I can't find any information to this. Referencing to this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

However, if, as you said the  timespan is really 1 week that it would be enough! I will def. accept your answer is the correct once, since it helps me pretty much.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search - "The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets."

So it can vary by a day or two, but it's more or less a week's worth of tweets that it'll search.

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I was looking for! Well this is enough, for the beginnging. Thanks to you